# Android json parsing is not working

Tags: android, json

Android json parsing is not working. My json string is

```
    [
      {"app":
        {"id":3,"image_title":"Fashion"}
        },
      {"app2":
        [
          {"id":3,"image_title":"Fashion"},
          {"id":3,"image_title":"Fashion"},
          {"id":3,"image_title":"Fashion"}
        ]
      }
    ]
```

But when i using this code

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
JSONArray app = jsonObj.getJSONArray("app");
    for (int i = 0; i < app.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = app.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = c.getString("id");
        String title = c.getString("image_title");
        Log.d("LOG", "id :"+id+" title :"+title);
        JSONObject app2 = jsonObj.getJSONObject("app2");
        for (int j = 0; j < app2.length(); j++) {
            String id1 = app2.getString("id");
            String title1 = app2.getString("image_title");
            Log.d("LOG", "id1 :"+id1+" title1 :"+title1);
        }

    }
```

not getting the output. 
The jsonStr is the json string where i given above.
I want to print the object id and title. How it possible? Please help me?

Comment: You're treating it as if the outermost element is an object. It's not; it's an array.

Comment: I have use getJSONArray("app")

Comment: Which is also wrong. You have an array containing two objects. One of those objects has an `app` key with an object value.

Comment: Can u rewrite the code?

Comment: Ha ha ha! Yeah, I could. I won't, though (not for free). I'll tell you what you need to do: (**0** Read up on JSON and its different data types.) **1** Parse the JSON as an *array*. **2** Get the 0th element from that array as an *object*. **3** Get another object from that object using the `app` key. **4** Add validation and error handling to the above.

Comment: Joe is your JSON structure correct? That is, is it way you want for your module?

Comment: @nitinkumarp My json is valid after checkin json validator in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Joe *Valid* JSON is not the same thing as *good* JSON. If you're in charge of the creation of that abomination, you *really* should rethink the structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is a `JSONArray` which consists of two `JSONObjects`. What you need to do is parse the array, retrieve the `JSONObject` via index and then parse those objects.

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
JSONObject firstObj = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject app1 = firstObj.getJSONObject("app");

//Parse your app1 here

JSONObject secObj = jArray.getJSONObject(1);
JSONObject app2 = secObj.getJSONArray("app2");

//Parse your app2 here
```

Remember, your first object i.e. `app1` is a `JSONObject`. So you can parse it using `app1.getString("image_title");`. Also, your second object i.e. `app2` is a `JSONArray` so you would have to retrieve `JSONObject` from it using indexes and then parse those `JSONObjects`

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < app2.length() ; i++) {
    JSONObject tmp = app2.getJSONObject(i);
    // Parse the object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is way strange. It has no structure as far as I can see. Parsing does not work because first `app` is a `JSONObject`:

```
"app":
        {"id":3,"image_title":"Fashion"}
        }
```

, but the second is a `JSONArray`:

```
"app2":
        [
          {"id":3,"image_title":"Fashion"},
          {"id":3,"image_title":"Fashion"},
          {"id":3,"image_title":"Fashion"}
        ]
```

You can do something like

```
JSONObject dataObject = json.optJSONObject("app");

if (dataObject != null) {

    //Do things with object.

} else {

    JSONArray array = json.optJSONArray("app");

    //Do things with array
}
```

Also your root object is not a `JSONObject`, but is a `JSONArray`.

Comment: @Joe, if I not though that my answer is correct, then I wouldn't post it. In general, you try to use JSONObject as JSONArray, and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

Use Below method to parse your response :

```
private void parseJsonResponse(String jsonString) {
        try {
            Object object = new JSONTokener(jsonString).nextValue();
            if (object != null) {
                if (object instanceof JSONArray) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) object;
                    if (jsonArray != null && jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            Object object1 = jsonArray.get(i);
                            if (object1 != null) {
                                if (object1 instanceof JSONObject) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object1;
                                    if (jsonObject != null) {
                                        if (jsonObject.has("app")) {
                                            Object object2 = jsonObject.get("app");
                                            if (object2 != null) {
                                                if (object2 instanceof JSONObject) {
                                                    JSONObject jsonObject3 = (JSONObject) object2;
                                                    String id = jsonObject3.optString("id");
                                                    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"id="+id);
                                                    String image_title = jsonObject3.optString("image_title");
                                                    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"image_title="+image_title);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } else if (jsonObject.has("app2")) {
                                            Object object2 = jsonObject.get("app2");
                                            if (object2 != null) {
                                                if (object2 instanceof JSONArray) {
                                                    JSONArray jsonArray1 = (JSONArray) object2;
                                                    if (jsonArray1 != null && jsonArray1.length() > 0) {
                                                        for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray1.length(); j++) {
                                                            Object object3 = jsonArray1.get(i);
                                                            if (object3 != null) {
                                                                if (object3 instanceof JSONObject) {
                                                                    JSONObject jsonObject3 = (JSONObject) object3;
                                                                    if (jsonObject3 != null) {
                                                                        String id = jsonObject3.optString("id");
                                                                        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"id="+id);
                                                                        String image_title = jsonObject3.optString("image_title");
                                                                        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"image_title="+image_title);
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I used JSONTokener to get upcoming object is JSONArray OR JSONObject .

Comment: Please give some reason for down vote , So I will improve my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);


            JSONObject jsonObjectApp = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject jsonObjectApp1 = jsonObjectApp.getJSONObject("app");
            String idApp = jsonObjectApp1.getString("id"); 
            String image_titleApp = jsonObjectApp1.getString("image_title");


        JSONObject jsonObjectApp2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1);
        JSONArray jsonArrayApp21 = jsonObjectApp2.getJSONArray("app2");
        for (int i = 0 ;i<jsonArrayApp21.length();i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObjectApp21 = jsonArrayApp21.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = jsonObjectApp21.getString("id");
            String image_title = jsonObjectApp21.getString("image_title");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```